# View returning None and not returning a response object django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

What I am working on is saving a new listing that is created by a given user on my commerce site, and displaying/redirecting the user to my index page. For some reason, the view keeps returning None and I'm not exactly sure why. Here is the code snippets below:

**views.py**

```
def createListing(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        listing = NewListingForm(request.POST)
        if listing.is_valid():
            creator = request.user
            title = listing.cleaned_data['title']
            price = listing.cleaned_data['price']
            description = listing.cleaned_data['description']
            image = listing.cleaned_data['image']
            category = listing.cleaned_data['category']

            # Using .objects.create much simpler solution
            auction = Listing.objects.create(
                creator=creator,
                title=title, 
                description=description, 
                price=price,
                category=category,
                image=image,
            )

            starting_bid = auction.price
            bid = Bid.objects.create(
                bid=starting_bid,
                user=creator,
                auction=auction
            )

            return render(request, "auctions/index.html", {
                "message": "Listing Created Successfully."
            })
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, "auctions/create.html", {
            "create_form": NewListingForm()
        })
```

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Comment(models.Model):
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_comment")

class Listing(models.Model):
    
    CATEGORIES = [
    ('Toys', 'Toys'),
    ('Electronics', 'Electronics'),
    ('Lifestyle', 'Lifestyle'),
    ('Home', 'Home'),
    ('Fashion', 'Fashion'),
    ('Other', 'Other')
    ]   

    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="creator")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, null=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=False, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=1064, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, choices=CATEGORIES)
    image = models.URLField(default='https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/52632898/161646398-6d49eca9-267f-4eab-a5a7-6ba6069d21df.png')
    starting_bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    bid_counter = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    winner = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)

    def _str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} by {self.creator}"

class Bid(models.Model):
    bid = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_bid")
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    auction = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.bid} made by {self.user}"
```

**The new listing form:**

```
# Creating a new listing form
class NewListingForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label='', min_length=2, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={"class": "form-control", "style": "margin-bottom: 10px", "placeholder": "Title"}))
    description = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={"class": "form-control", "style": "margin-bottom: 10px", "placeholder": "Description"}))
    price = forms.DecimalField(label='', widget=forms.NumberInput(
        attrs={"class": "form-control", "style": "margin-bottom: 10px", "placeholder": "Starting Bid ($)"}))
    image = forms.ImageField(label="Choose an Image for your Listing")
    category = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        label='Pick a Category', widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=Listing.CATEGORIES)
```

I have tried looking into urls.py to ensure I was calling the right view with its according name and using 'return redirect('index')' but it doesn't seem to work either. I'm relatively new to django so any help would be appreciated! Let me know if there are any other files that are required to help clarify the problem.

Comment: The condition under which you fail to return a response is pretty obvious: `request.method == "POST"`, but not `listing.is_valid()`.  You need to explicitly handle that case, too.

Comment: As already stated, you only returning something if the listing is valid, otherwise you are not returning anything and this case Python returns `None`. Also, you do not have to write a form model if you already have a Listing model, remember the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @EduardoMatsuoka Yeah looking at it now I see where my logic failed, also thanks for the tip on the form model! I got it to work by directly using the Listing model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django handled http `GET` method automatically not needing to write it, and also need to remove the unwanted stuff.

your code becomes like this...

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib import messages
def createListing(request):
    listing =NewListingForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        listing = NewListingForm(request.POST)
        if listing.is_valid():
            creator = request.user
            title = listing.cleaned_data['title']
            price = listing.cleaned_data['price']
            description = listing.cleaned_data['description']
            image = listing.cleaned_data['image']
            category = listing.cleaned_data['category']

            # Using .objects.create much simpler solution
            auction = Listing.objects.create(
                creator=creator,
                title=title,
                description=description,
                price=price,
                category=category,
                image=image,
            )

            starting_bid = auction.price
            bid = Bid.objects.create(
                bid=starting_bid,
                user=creator,
                auction=auction
            )
            messages.success(request,"Listing Created Successfully")
            return redirect("/home/")
    context = {
        "listing": listing
    }
    return render(request, "auctions/create.html", context)
```